# iOS - Add message to NotificationCenter/MessageCenter

Tags: objective-c, notifications, notificationcenter

I have a real problem to access the notification/message center (the one with the weather widget).

The only thing I want to do is, getting a notification text there and I really find no tutorial or anything else ...

May someone please give me a hint?

Thanks a lot and greetings,
matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it to be a remote message?

ios 5 has the idea of a local notification which lets your app just post a notification from the device.

http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/ios-local-notifications-tutorial/

Comment: sorry, but his answer is the one I was searching for ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)